# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object - while reading jsonelement

Tags: json, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to find a property on my Jsonelement using the below code. This works fine when the element is not element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined .But when the element doesnot have a property which i am searching it gives me an error Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

```
private static JsonElement GetJsonElement(JsonElement element, string property)
{
    JsonElement outJsonElement;

    if (element.TryGetProperty(property, out outJsonElement))
    {
        return outJsonElement;
    }
    return outJsonElement;
}
```

In order to overcome the error i have added a validation before checking the trygetproperty() method

```
private static JsonElement GetJsonElement(JsonElement element, string property)
{
    JsonElement outJsonElement;

    if (element.ValueKind != JsonValueKind.Undefined && element.TryGetProperty(property, out outJsonElement))
    {
        return outJsonElement;
    }
    return outJsonElement;
}
```

and this is the call

```
myClass.Object= GetJsonElement(myjsonelement, "myproperty").GetString();
```

But here i receive error on the last statement(  return outJsonElement;) use of unassigned local variableoutJsonElement. Can you suggest me to find a default value in case of the property is not found.

Comment: The problem with the first is that you're returning a `JsonElement` with default values, which is unspecified, and thus `GetString` is not able to return something. You will either have to return something that makes sense to call `GetString` on or you will have to check the result outside to see if it is sane to call GetString on it before you do.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen if i didnt find a a properrty what default value i can asssign to a JsonElement